# (c++) Advanced Geospatial Analysis Library

Tags: software-recommendations, c++

I've been searching for a lightweight library for geospatial analysis, with low overhead. [Yesterday I found TurfJS, looks great, simple and fast, yet, its made in JS.](http://turfjs.org/)

Does anyone know similar libraries, also lightweight, but for C++? I tried searching, but I'm fairly new to GIS so I have no clue on how to refer to such libs.

Comment: What sort of geospatial analysis?

Answer (score 3):

GEOS? I'm not sure what your definition of "lightweight" is, or whether anything can be both "lightweight" and "advanced" but GEOS is the main open-source geographical data analysis package, used in QGIS and R:

https://libgeos.org/

Has C++ bindings.

If you're after geometry operations, then maybe CGAL: https://www.cgal.org/